# highlight zoomed feature

Tags: openlayers

I have features in drop down list.when I select feature in drop down it is zooming to that layer.Now I wanted to highlight that zoomed feature.how can I style the zoomed feature?

can any one help me to achieve it?

here is my zooming function:

```
    var owsURL = "http://192.168.1.137:8080/geoserver/school/ows";
var SearchResultsLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    id: 'SearchResultsLayer',
    style: function (feature, resolution) {
        style.getText().setText(resolution < 5000 ? feature.get('') : '');
        return styles;
    }
});

function Zoomto(filter, SearchResultsLayer) {
    var schoolname = $('#ddlschool').val();
    alert(schoolname);
    var filter = "talukname='" + schoolname + "'";
    alert(filter);
    $.ajax({
        url: owsURL,
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback: "parseResponse",
        data: {
            typeName: "school:taluk",
            outputFormat: "text/javascript",
            service: "WFS",
            version: "1.1.0",
            request: "GetFeature",
            CQL_FILTER: filter

        },
        success: function (response) {

            var SearchResultsLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({});

            SearchResultsLayer.setSource(null);

            var searchresultssource = new ol.source.Vector({
                features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(response, {
                    featureProjection: "EPSG:3857"
                })
            });

            SearchResultsLayer.setSource(searchresultssource);
            map.getView().fit(SearchResultsLayer.getSource().getExtent(), map.getSize());

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `feature.set("key", value)` to set a property on a feature. F.e. in the zoom function, do `feature.set("zoomed", true)` on all features.

And in your style you can of course get that key to adapt your style. So 

`if (feature.get("zoomed")) {
  // add some style highlight
}`

It's possible the icons don't get refreshed automatically, then you need to mark them as dirty with a `feature.changed()` call.

Comment: Also, please don't post duplicates: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175308/highlight-zoomed-feature

Comment: its not working with me